Coordinates changing in ChemDraw3D when editing and saving .sdf file
I am using ChemDraw to edit an SDF file, but I am facing an issue:
Every time I open and save the SDF file in ChemDraw, the molecular structure coordinates are altered. I want to keep the original coordinates unchanged.
(The issue isn't that I need to change the coordinates; when I open the file in ChemDraw 3D, it automatically modifies the coordinates upon display. The coordinates are altered before I make any changes or save the file. My goal is to view the file without any automatic modifications to the original coordinates.)
Here is an example of my file:
Unnamed
  Chem3D Core 23.1.1

  3  2  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0999 V2000
   -2.1598   -0.4186   -0.0478 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    0.8754   -0.0150   -0.1135 H   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   -0.8754    0.4186    0.1135 H   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
  1  2  1  0        0
  1  3  1  0        0
M  END
$$$$

But then it becomes
Unnamed
  Chem3D Core 23.1.1

  3  2  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0999 V2000
   -0.2986   -0.4954   -0.0067 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    0.8044   -0.3487   -0.0306 H   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   -0.8044    0.4954    0.0306 H   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
  1  2  1  0        0
  1  3  1  0        0
M  END
$$$$

I have tried the following methods but none of them worked:

Looking for settings in ChemDraw to disable coordinate optimization
but couldn't find any.
Editing the file using a text editor (the coordinates still
change when I open it again.)

Is there a way to edit and save an SDF file in ChemDraw without changing the original coordinates?
Thank you for your help!

Then why edit in the first place?

@Mithoron  The issue isn't that I need to change the coordinates; it's that when I open the file in ChemDraw 3D, it automatically modifies the coordinates upon display. The coordinates are altered even before I make any changes or save the file. My goal is to view the file without any automatic modifications to the original coordinates. Thanks, I need to update my questions.

And what part of the sdf file do you want to edit while preserving the atomic coordinates? If we zoom out to see the greater picture, what does the workflow overall intend? For instance, do you aim to eventually submit the structure to a computation with Gaussian, MOPAC, ...?

@Buttonwood My main goal is to ensure that these molecular structures remain accurate for visualization and further use. Currently, I do not plan to use these structures for computational programs like Gaussian or MOPAC; it's primarily for viewing and managing the molecular information in ChemDraw.

Short answer: import of the .sdf by ChemDraw sketcher instead of by the 3D viewer.
Personal perspective:

A .sdf file is a chemical structure file already containing atomic coordinates suitable for a molecule viewer like for instance Avogadro2, Jmol, or ChemDraw's 3D structure viewer program, to display a molecule, for instance, ball-stick like as you can do with a physical model kit, or/and to use for further computation of molecular properties with programs like Gaussian, MOPAC, etc.*

(image credit NC State University Library)

Another aspect of chemistry is the visual representation of molecules in schemes, for instance, to depict the presumed mechanism of a reaction which is more about structure drawing, e.g.

(image credit)
as provided by the ChemDraw sketcher alone, i.e. as a molecule editor.  Then, the retention of a .cdxml file is more suitable for that for instance the submission of the drawing according to the policies of another journal only is a matter of applying the publisher's style template.**  The automated optimization of the structure you seem to describe is a feature of the 3D viewer.


The combination of Strg + Shift + k to clean up a 2D scheme in ChemDraw is somewhat arbitrary, aiming to keep the drawing readable and visually pleasing.  This sometimes contradicts with what is "chemically speaking" reasonable.  This is a problem for every 2D projection of 3D molecules, only a matter of e.g., the number of congested stereogenic centers in a polycyclic structure present ... you get the picture.

* You already have a non-zero $z$ component of the atomic coordinates.  This suggests you used Chem3D and not the mere editor/sketcher of ChemDraw to export the .sdf files.  Maleic anhydride would be exported by ChemDraw as a flat 2D structure without explicit hydrogen atoms:
ACS Document 1996
  ChemDraw04132110502D

  7  7  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0999 V2000
   -0.6348    0.4125    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   -0.6348   -0.4125    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    0.1498   -0.6674    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    0.6348    0.0000    0.0000 O   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    0.1498    0.6674    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    0.4048    1.4521    0.0000 O   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    0.4048   -1.4521    0.0000 O   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
  1  2  2  0      
  2  3  1  0      
  3  4  1  0      
  4  5  1  0      
  5  1  1  0      
  5  6  2  0      
  3  7  2  0      
M  END

** Though your mileage may vary, the binary .cdx, or plain text .cdxml can be read, or written by other programs than ChemDraw itself, too (e.g., ChemDoodle, Marvin; openbabel) to provide a conversion e.g., to .sdf files.
